# When should I use entityManager.flush() if i am already using @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am using ***JPA in Spring Boot Application***.

I am only getting starting to use It and I have some questions.

My ***DAO*** code is the following:

```
@Transactional
public class DatabaseUnitDao implements IDatabaseUnitDao {

@PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
    public void create(Unit unit) {
        final String CREATE_UNIT =
                "CREATE TABLE " + unit.getName() + " (id VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, value text NOT NULL)";
        entityManager.persist(unit);   // add an info about unit in the general table
        entityManager.createNativeQuery(CREATE_UNIT).executeUpdate(); // create table for this units
    }
}
```

***1.Should I use `flush()` in this case?***

***2.Is It enough to just annotate DAO class with @Transactional?***

Some resources tell that it's needed to use ***@EnableTransactionManagement***  to use @Transactional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No. JPA provider has to do it for you at the end of the transactional method's invocation.
2. Yes. Spring Boot enables transaction management by default (with proxyTargetClass = true)